# Can I use a DC-DC boost converter to increase voltage at one part of a circuit, to ultimately increase current in a later part of the circuit?

Tags: voltage, current, dc-dc-converter, resistance, boost

[image]

As you can see in the example above, I want a target current across my 50 ohm resistor of 4 A which would require a voltage of 100 V, but my power supply is only 10 V. Can I use a boost converter (as shown above) to increase the voltage to 100 V to achieve a 4 A current across the resistor later on? If not, what am I missing here?

Assume a Vin of 10 V and 40 A.

Comment: if "Vout" is 100V/1A then there can't be 4A going trough the resistor. Also, is it 25 ohm or 50 ohm ? The drawing and text are inconsistent.

Comment: Is the question "Can a boost converter take 40A at 10V and produce 4A at 100v"? If there are no losses in the system, yes. Otherwise, you will need more input power to overcome losses.

Comment: You mention a 50 ohm resistor, but the schematic and all your calculations seem to use a 25 Ω resistor. Which is it?

Comment: A lot of inconsistencies between the drawing and your text. I'd suggest correcting this first to get a more accurate answer..

Answer (score 4):

You are taking 100 watts in from your power supply, and asking for 400 watts into your resistor. That cannot happen continuously, you can't get energy from nowhere.

You could do do this intermittently. There's nothing wrong with storing energy and releasing it at a higher rate later. You could charge a capacitor at 100 watts, and then discharge it for a short while at 400 watts. You would only be able to power your load for 25% of the time assuming no converter losses, less (perhaps 15-20%) of the time once converter losses has been taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

In theory yes, but of output needs 100V at 4A which is 400 watts, at least same amount of input power is needed, which at 10V input voltage means that at least 40A is needed.